# Changed A record and CNAME for tumblr, but now all links un-associated with Tumblr error

Tags: redirects, tumblr

Is there a way to link to a custom forum when the A Record and CNAME force everything through TUMBLR?

Comment: You should add some more detail about what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't quote understand the question, if your forum is hosted else ware you can just create a "forum" A record and point it to your forum IP address. Then you should be able to access forum.youdomain.com